# ERROR in Twitterizer.OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken() "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: String"

Tags: c#, twitter, twitterizer

Here's the line where I get that error:

```cs
var requestToken = OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken(
    _consumerKey, 
    _consumerSecret, 
    "http://mysite.com/Twitter/GetToken");
```

_consumerKey and _consumerSecret have proper values.

Stack Trace:

> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: String]
>     System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +9585854
>     System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +119
>     Twitterizer.TwitterizerException.ParseRateLimitHeaders(WebResponse response) in C:\Projects\twitterizer-132\Twitterizer2\Exceptions\TwitterizerException.cs:200
>     Twitterizer.TwitterizerException..ctor(String message, Exception innerException) in C:\Projects\twitterizer-132\Twitterizer2\Exceptions\TwitterizerException.cs:98
>     Twitterizer.OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken(String consumerKey, String consumerSecret, String callbackAddress) in C:\Projects\twitterizer-132\Twitterizer2\OAuth\OAuthUtility.cs:95
>     Brace.Twitter.Tweeting.GetRequestTokenUrl() in D:\PROJECTS\Brace\v1\Brace.Twitter\Tweeting.cs:18
>     Brace.Controllers.TwitterController.GetToken(String oauth_token, String oauth_verifier) in D:\PROJECTS\Brace\v1\Brace\Controllers\TwitterController.cs:15
>     lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +157
>     System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
>     System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +208
>     System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
>     System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass15.b*_12() +55
>     System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +263
>     System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +19
>     System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +191
>     System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
>     System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
>     System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
>     System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
>     System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
>     System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
>     System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult *) +12
>     System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
>     System.Web.Mvc.<>c*_DisplayClasse.b_*d() +50
>     System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.b*_0(Action f) +7
>     System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
>     System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
>     System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>     System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8963149
>     System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my best attempt at being overly vague: this bug is actually a symptom of another issue.

More than likely, your application (not your actual application, but the registration with Twitter that gave you your console token) is not set up as a web application. Their form is misleading: it doesn't make the callback url required when you select a web app, but it actually is required. When you save your app without a callback url, it actually saves it as a desktop app.

The problem with a desktop app is that you can't use callback urls. Web apps can used pin-based authentication, but desktop apps can't use web-based authentication. (I'm sure there's a perfectly good reason.)

So, twitter is rejecting your request to get a request token, because you're also providing a callback.

The actual exception is because Twitterizer is still looking for rate limit information that's included in every (well, ok, almost-every) response, even from requests that failed.

I will (finally) fix that issue, but it won't solve your real problem.

Comment: Thanks! It is indeed misleading, but now I saw the fine print :)  "To restrict your application from using callbacks, leave this field blank."  After I added callback URL everything works fine now. Thanks for fast response!

Comment: Anil and @ThePower : The release posted yesterday should have addressed this issue.